# Getting a list of function definition parameter values

Tags: functions, function-construction

If I define a function over certain values:

```
f[0] = 1
f[1] = 2
f[2] = 3
```

How do I get the list of parameter values that it's been defined on?

```
ie. FunctionValues[f]
{0,1,2}
```

Comment: `DownValues[f][[All, 1, 1, 1]]`.